# Is There A way to get a 3d object point to the mouse in the same way a 2d object would unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector

I tried making the player look at the mouse in the same way that a 2d player would. I eventually made it do that but I don't understand how. I used a 3d cube a perspective camera and put a rigid body on the cube and added constraints on the x and z rotations.

Following code makes player turn

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mouseLook1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    public int offset = 0;

    Vector3 mousePos;
    Vector3 rotation;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit)) {
            //transform.position = hit.point;

            mousePos = hit.point;
        }
        rotation = new Vector3(mousePos.x-transform.position.x, mousePos.y-transform.position.y,mousePos.z-transform.position.z);
        rotation.y = 0;

        transform.forward = rotation;
    }
}
```

I don't understand how that made the player turn

Comment: Well you changed its rotation...

Comment: `I eventually made it do that but I don't understand how.` ... o.O .. means? You copy pasted some code from somewhere else and now want an explanation what it does? Well you set `transform.forward = rotation;` which internally modifies the orientation of your object ... if this is a `Rigidbody` as you say you shouldn't use this though but rather go through `Rigibody.MoveRotation` or `Rigidbody.rotation` using `Quaternion.LookRotation` on th vector you currently use as the forward ;)

Comment: Im sorry but that didn't answer my question, it is my fault for not clearly stating it. In the code, that I wrote by the way, first I used transform.up = rotation as I thought that would change the Y rotation but it changed the Z rotation. then I used transform.forward which changed the y rotation. I am curious about how transform.forward and not transform.up changed the Y rotation of the player.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that your code will work only if you have some other object where you hit raycast.

You can use [transfrom.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)

```cs
    void Update()
    {
       Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    
       if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit)) {
          //transform.position = hit.point;
    
            mousePos = hit.point;
       }
       rotation = mousePos - transform.position;
       rotation.y = transform.y;
    
       transform.LookAt(rotation);
     }
```

Let me know if you need help.

UPD:
In case you dont have collider to raycast you can use [Plane](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.html) and [Plane.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.Raycast.html)

```cs
var objectPlane = new Plane(transfrom.position, transfrom.up);

var cameraRay = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); //cache your camera via [SerializeField] or in Awake use cameraField = Camera.main, avoid usage of Camera.main

float enter = 0.0f;

if (objectPlane.Raycast(ray, out enter))
{
   //Get the point that is clicked
   Vector3 hitPoint = ray.GetPoint(enter);
   rotation.x = transform.x;
    
   transform.LookAt(rotation);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for teling me that the code may not work unless there is an object underneath it. Is there a way to counter that?

Comment: The one possible way is to create ray from camera, and create plane from position of controlled object and it's transfrom.up. I'll post update to answer since it's not fits here.